# One line bash command for downloading Maven artifacts for a pom to a specified lib

Tags: maven, awk, sed, ant

Here is as far as I got:

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep ":compile" | sed 's/+//' | sed 's/-//' | sed 's/\\//' | sed 's/\|//g' | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/:jar:/:/'| sed 's/:compile//' | sed 's/:/,/g' | sed 's/\[INFO\]//'
```

Yes it is rudimentary. I'm thinking theres a 'cut' usage in there and maybe awk to construct a line for curl/wget for `http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4/xstream-1.4.jar` but my Bash fu isn't there.

Obviously the subsequent curl/wget bit is the easy one, given all the piping going on. It's just the URL construction that's out of reach.

This is what comes out of the end of what I have (so you don't have to understand Maven):

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream,xstream,1.4
```

Comment: Clearly specify your _input_ and the exact _output_ you need out of it

Comment: See output from the working Python script below, if you think a bash one-liner is still possible, Inian :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can't do it with a oneliner, as asked, but a small Python script fits the bill:

```
# pip3 install sh
from sh import mvn, grep, rm, mkdir, sed, wget
import csv

rm("-rf", "libs")
mkdir("libs")

tree = sed(sed(mvn("dependency:tree", _tty_out=False), "s/\\[INFO\\]//"), "/\\[WARNING\\]/d")
lines = sed(sed(sed(sed(sed(sed(sed(sed(tree, "s/+//"), "s/-//"), "s/\\\//"), "s/\|//g"), "s/ //g"), "s/:jar:/:/"), "s/:/,/g"), "s/\[INFO\]//")

for gav in csv.reader(lines):
    if (len(gav) is not 4):
        continue

    mkdir("-p", "libs/" + gav[3])
    try:
        wget("http://central.maven.org/maven2/" + gav[0].replace(".", "/") + "/" + gav[1] + "/" + gav[2] + "/" + gav[1] + "-" + gav[2] + ".jar", "-O", "libs/" + gav[3] + "/" + gav[1] + "-" + gav[2] + ".jar")
    except:
        pass
```

As used in anger on `https://github.com/paul-hammant/spring-jetty-integrationtest-ant-example/blob/master/mavdl.py` (demo project)

Edit: There's also an Ant capability for Maven Resolver, I'm told: https://maven.apache.org/resolver-archives/resolver-ant-tasks-LATEST/